# Jenkins Using result artifacts in different steps - stash and unstash

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a Jenkinsfile declarative pipeline which has two steps:

1. build an RPM file inside a docker container
2. build a docker image with the RPM and run it

The first step is built inside a docker container because it require a specific app to build the RPM.

The second step is run directly on a Jenkins slave, can be other slave than the slave which ran the first step.

In order to use the RPM produced by the first step I'm currently using `stash` and `unstash` steps. If I do not use them the second step doesn't have access to the RPM file.

The RPM file is about 215MB which is more than the 100MB recommended limit so I'll like to know if there is a better solution?

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    options {
        timestamps()
    }

    stages {

        stage('Gradle: build') {
            agent {
                docker {
                    image 'some-internal-image'
                }
            }

            steps {
                sh """
                    chmod +x gradlew
                    ./gradlew buildRpm
                """
            }

            post {
                success {
                    stash name: 'rpm', includes: 'Server/target/myapp.rpm'
                }
            }
        }

        stage('Gradle: build docker image') {
            steps {
                unstash 'rpm'
                sh """
                    chmod +x gradlew
                    ./gradlew buildDockerImage
                """
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use docker's [multi-stage build](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/multistage-build/), but I'm not aware of a nice implementation using Jenkins Pipelines.

We're stashing also several hundreds of megabytes to distribute it to build agents. I've experimented with uploading the artifacts to S3 and downloading them again from there with now visible performance improvement (only that it takes off load from the Jenkins Master).

So my very opinionated recommendation: Keep it like it is and optimize, once you really run into performance / load issues.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [Artifactory](https://jfrog.com/artifactory/) or any other binary repository manager..

From Artifactory's webpage:

> As the first, and only, universal Artifact Repository Manager on the
>   market, JFrog Artifactory fully supports software packages created by
>   any language or technology.
>
> ...
>
> ...Artifactory provides an end-to-end, automated and bullet-proof
>   solution for tracking artifacts from development to production.